# What's new with PHP 5.4?

Tags: php

I've been using class traits and the shortened array syntax and haven't really done any more research beyond that point because they are the two main features I've seen and use daily, what else should we be aware of?

One of the new features I'm unsure of is the built in HTTP sever. How exactly does this work, and what if any security risks does this pose?

Comment: http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php

Comment: The http server isn't recommended for production - it's just for development.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to see everything that's changed, take a look at the changelog. If you want to get a quick overview of some of the cooler things that have changed, I presented recently on it. You can see the presentation here:  http://prezi.com/cbjdu1vtrpgm/php-54/

The changelog is at http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php

If you're interested in what the new built-in web server brings, it's pretty cool. You can start the server with

```
php -S <ip address>:<port>

i.e.

php -S 127.0.0.1:8888
```

You should start the server in the document root of what you want it to serve up. If you need to do routing or anything that Apache's .htaccess would do, you can write a PHP script and specify it for the router like so:

```
php -S <ip address>:<port> router.php
```

The router works in a way that if your script returns false, it will serve up the file in the directory/path it would normally be found in. Otherwise your script can include other files, or do whatever you need it to. A very basic router example is on the php.net documentation site:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php#example-369

I think one of the best things with the built in server in PHP 5.4 is that it will make it so much easier for people who are just starting to learn PHP to be able to learn without having to get Apache or some other web server installed and configured.

That being said, it's only for learning and I don't think anyone would recommend running a real production server with the built-in web server.

Comment: Ok so you can actually run a server in a directory?  Or in root?  that's where I get confused.  What if I'm already running Apache and start the php server in the same directory, will they conflict with each other?

Comment: You can run the php internal server anywhere you would like. The directory you start it in is similar to the DocumentRoot in apache. You specify the IP to bind to and the port when you start the PHP server so if Apache is already running, you would not be able to specify the same port(s) as what apache is listening on.

Comment: your presentation is AWESOME.

Comment: Thanks, I am glad you liked it.